# Calculate Surface Area of a Bicubic Bezier Surface Patch

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, bezier-curve

Given the 16 3D control points as input for a bicubic Bézier surface patch, how would one go about calculating the surface area of such a patch?

Comment: This sounds to be an interesting question. Can you tell why knowing the area will be useful in general?

Comment: @JohnMa -- Suppose your going to paint it. You'd want to know how much paint you'll need. Suppose you're going to make it from sheet metal (like the body of a car or the hull of a ship). You'd like to know how much it will weigh.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to decompose it into triangles, and add up the areas of the triangles.

Alternatively, just call your favorite numerical quadrature function. Adding up triangles is just a very simple form of numerical quadrature, of course.

If you search, you'll find lots of info about calculating the arclength of a Bezier curve. Calculating the area of a Bezier patch is the 2D analog of this, and similar techniques are applicable.

There is no closed-form formula for the area.